# Class instance being shared by multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a web app hosted on Azure that shares messages among users from a table called `Message` located in a SQL Azure database. My project contains a class to keep track of current user information called `CurrentUser.cs`. It contains properties like `Username`, `RoomID`, `JoinTime`, etc. I'm having difficulty understanding what happens with this class when another user logs in. I originally thought that every user would have their own instance of `CurrentUser` that would not be accessible by others. Here's what I'm seeing:

If `UserA` logs in, they are able to post messages and the messages display with their username. When `UserB` logs in, they are also able to post messages with their username. If `UserA` posts a message after `UserB` has logged in, their messages display with `UserB`'s username. This leads me to believe that `UserA`'s `CurrentUser.cs` file is being overwritten when `UserB` signs in. How can this be? I thought every time someone visited my site, a new instance of `CurrentUser.cs` would exist. Is this not the case? Do all of my users share the same `CurrentUser` class as I currently have it?

**EDIT**

I have a constructor inside `CurrentUser` that sets properties when the app loads. I never call `CurrentUser user = new CurrentUser()` or anything. My question is more about whether or not each user has their own version of `CurrentUser.cs` or not. I was under the impression that I did not have to create an instance of `CurrentUser` because each visitor would have their own.

```
    static CurrentUser()
    {
        MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();

        _username = membershipUser.UserName;
        _providerKey = (Guid)membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;

        UserProfile profile = UserProfileController.GetByProviderKey(_providerKey);

        _userID = profile.UserID;
        _roomID = profile.RoomID;
        _joinRoomTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

        DisplayedMessages = new List<Message>();
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

My properties are static but my class is not. Perhaps this has something to do with it?

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted your class definition here. There are too many variables in your question without code. Your class could be static, or stored in static variable, etc

Comment: Yes. The answer lies in your code. We can't speculate about what mistake you might have made.

Comment: You have to show us where CurrentUser is instantiated.

Comment: You need to have instance class and instance members for each user. Static members are shared between all instances - this is your problem

Comment: @T.S. - I thought it was something simple. Many thanks.